# Ionic - Facebook Native Ads Error 1001 (No fill)

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic3, native-ads

My facebook native ads integration code is like below.

```
var that = this;
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
if(FacebookAds)
{
  //FacebookAds.setOptions({
    //isTesting: true,
    //deviceHash: 'fe645f07-9801-41fe-a430-xxxxxxxxxxx'
  //},(s)=>(console.log("settings are OK.")),(e)=>(console.log("Settings are not loaded...")));

  FacebookAds.createNativeAd('xxxxxxxxx',
    (eee) => {
      document.addEventListener("onAdLoaded", (data) =>{
        console.log(data);
        let temp: any = data;
        if(temp.adType == "native")
        {
          this.startFB = 1;
          document.getElementById('adIcon').setAttribute("src", decodeURIComponent(temp.adRes.icon.url));
          document.getElementById('adCover').setAttribute("src", decodeURIComponent(temp.adRes.coverImage.url));
          document.getElementById('adTitle').innerHTML = temp.adRes.title;
          document.getElementById('adBody').innerHTML = temp.adRes.body;
          document.getElementById('adSocialContext').innerHTML = temp.adRes.socialContext;
          document.getElementById('adBtn').innerHTML = temp.adRes.buttonText;
          that.updateXY(0, 0);
        }
      });
      document.addEventListener('onAdFailLoad', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        //alert('error: ' + data);
      });
    },
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
}
});
```

1. When I run this code **without** test mode, I get 1001 error code.
2. When I run this code **with** test mode, No error but load data comes empty.

**Not:** I test code in real device and I login as test user to Facebook app in this device.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: confirming this as a pattern. On my production build, ads are coming up, but on test device, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Facebook ads fill rate is not good so most of time that return no fill. Actually, after all I exchange my platform from ionic to react-native. Because react-native is more suitable for ads.